# Could the Google App Engine be used to drive a desktop application?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have the impression that the Google App Engine allows an interface for developers to make use of Google's servers for storing custom application data in a highly scalable and cost effective way. Whilst working through their tutorials, it seems like tools are focused on aiding the development of 'web applications'.

I'm looking to take advantage of the GAE in order to serve data for a platform independent desktop application that I'm writing in Java, so my end product will not rest within the confines of a browser. Is this functionality supported by the GAE?

Comment: yes, people write Android apps that use GAE as a backend for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea! you can do that.
So basically, you are going to build a native application and use API calls to send/receive data from a server(GAE). I see a good solution will be to

- Build your API endpoints using the Endpoints lib https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints
- Then, depending on your application you can make API calls directly or build a client library